# AutoRest generation: How to keep a List<int> a List<int> and not List<int?>

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autorest

When generating a WebApi with Micrsoft RestClient there are a number of rules to be considered, for example you need to flag all `ValueType` (like `int` or `System.Guid`) as `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute` or else AutoRest will make them `System.Nullable<T>` in the generated code.

But how do I do this to keep a `List<int>` a `List<int>` and not `List<int?>`? Using `[Required]`did not help any in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try registering an ISchemaFilter like so, which should cover both generic collections as well as arrays:

```
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        var type = context.Type;

        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetInterface(nameof(IEnumerable)) != null)
        {
            if (type.GenericTypeArguments.Any(genericTypeArgument => genericTypeArgument.IsValueType)) 
                AddNonNullableFieldToSchema(schema);
        }
        else if (type.IsArray && type.GetElementType()?.IsValueType == true)
        {
            AddNonNullableFieldToSchema(schema);
        }
    }

    private static void AddNonNullableFieldToSchema(OpenApiSchema)
    {
        schema.Items.Extensions["x-nullable"] = new OpenApiBoolean(false);
    }
```

Comment: And what happens in `AddNonNullableFieldToSchema(schema)`?

Comment: *Edited* to include the missing method, sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks I will try it out.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to work. I tried with this mini controller:
`public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(MyResponse))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetStuff()
    {
        return Ok(new MyResponse());
    }
}

public class MyResponse
{
    [Required]
    public int Hotz { get; set; }

    public List<int> Hurz { get; set; }
}` and `Apply()` is only called for `IHttpActionResult` and `MyResponse` but not for `List<int>`